# Missing ViewsLifeTime when querying

Tags: 2013, search-results, publishing-page

I am using a search query to show the most popular publishing page and ordering by ViewsLifeTime.  There were values present yesterday but now they are gone not even a 0 is seen?

Screeshot from SharePoint Search query tool
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe the propertiy `ViewsLifeTime` is not Searchable and Consumable.